# Which in-app billing library should I use in app targeting both mobiles and tablets?

Tags: in-app-purchase, android

The Market's policy on in-app billing says:

> If your device is running Android 3.0, in-app billing requires version
>   5.0.12 (or higher) of the MyApps application. If your device is
>   running any other version of Android, in-app billing requires version
>   2.3.4 (or higher) of the Android Market application.

I planned to use SDK 3.1 so that the app works both on mobile phones and tablets. If I want to use in-app billing in the app targeting both mobile devices and tablets as well, which library should I use?

Should I just use version 5.0.12? If yes, will the in-app billing work on the mobile phones?

Or I should use both libraries and check if the device is a mobile phone or a tablet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no library for this, just an AIDL file so you can connect to the Market in-app billing service. Those version numbers are referring to the apps installed on the device. You can use any SDK (above 1.6) you want, but you need to test on a real device with Android Market. You can't test in-app billing on an emulator.

Comment: I know I can't test it because it's clearly stated in the documentation. I did not realize they are referring to Market app version, but I thought they are referring to the library version. Thanks for the answer.